# Angular redirection for partial case insensitivity

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have some paths like so:

```js
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'championships/:region', component: ChampionshipsComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'championships/USA', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'championships/USA', pathMatch: 'full'},
    ])
```

What I'd like to be the case, is to allow a user typing a URL with any letters in `championships` being capitalized. I don't want to just `toLowerCase()` the entire URL, because the `:region` part of the URL is case sensitive.

Some examples if a user enters any of the following:
`http://localhost:4200/championships/USA`
`http://localhost:4200/Championships/USA`
`http://localhost:4200/CHAMPIONSHIPS/USA`
`http://localhost:4200/ChAMPioNShipS/USA`

I'd like it all to land on the same page. Ideally I'd normalize the URL so that it redirects to, `http://localhost:4200/championships/USA`, but most important is that they all load the same `ChampionshipsComponent`

Is there a way I can do that just within the `RouterModule.forRoot()` function? I'm hoping its a simple redirection with some regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below url serializer provider statement to the app.module.ts

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {
    // Optional Step: Do some stuff with the url if needed.

    // If you lower it in the optional step 
    // you don't need to use "toLowerCase" 
    // when you pass it down to the next function
    return super.parse(url.toLowerCase()); 
  }
}
```

AND

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
        provide: UrlSerializer,
        useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```